# Blur background when I pause my game in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, core-image

I have a handler for my game that pauses it, and when it does, I want the stuff in the background (that is, stuff "behind" the pause box) to have a Gaussian Blur sort of effect.

My game uses SpriteKit and Objective-C to run, and I don't have much of an idea of how to use a `CIFilter` (I'm guessing that's how I'm going to render said effect).

I saw this question: [Copy a picture of the current screen just before game pause blur it and render to screen in the duration of game pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051437/copy-a-picture-of-the-current-screen-just-before-game-pause-blur-it-and-render-t), but this example is in Java, and I'm taking a huge guess and saying this is also the wrong technology.

My goal is to have the blurred background as a node, with a `zPosition`, so I can layer it correctly?

Can someone help me clarify what I need to do to achieve the effect I'm describing?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial

Comment: Look at this Q&A. The second (not accepted answer) gives a detailed explanation on how to achieve an image blur. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view